# JQuery DataTables RowGrouping: Moving row from one group to another

Tags: jquery, datatables, grouping

I'm using jQuery + dataTables + rowGrouping to render a table where rows are grouped by the values of a certain column. Before applying the rowGrouping feature it looks something like this:

```
Task           | Status  | Buttons
-------------------------------------
Test something | Stopped | Start
Eat cake       | Started | Stop
Take a break   | Stopped | Start
```

and after rowGrouping:

```
Task           | Buttons
-------------------------------------
STARTED
Eat cake       | Stop
-------------------------------------
STOPPED
Take a break   | Start
Test something | Start
```

(the status column is now hidden and the values are used to create the STARTED/STOPPED grouping rows - so far so good).

Here is the code that initializes the dataTable:

```
var dataTable = $("#table")
  .dataTable({
    'bLengthChange': false,
    'bPaginate': false,
    'sScrollX': "100%",
    'bScrollCollapse': true,
  })
  .rowGrouping({
    'bExpandableGrouping': true,
    'sGroupingColumnSortDirection': 'asc',
    'iGroupingColumnIndex': 1, 
    'iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex': 0
  });
```

My problem now is, that I want to attach an onclick handler to the buttons. Clicking a Start button should change the status of that task to Started, and the task should move to the STARTED group.

But I just cannot figure out how to accomplish this :(

My first idea was to just call .rowGrouping() again on the table object, but that is not allowed. I have also tried updating the status cell of the row containing the clicked button using API functions like fnUpdate(), but I have failed miserably.

I have found a hint of how to move a row to another group in the last section of this page:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/RowGrouping

but I have spent all day trying to make it work and I cannot figure it out.

Help please :)